# Refactor if statements in PHP or another solution for if statements (not switch case)

Tags: php, mysql, refactoring

I have some if statements in my code.
e.g:

```
if($option[0]->posts == 1 && $option[0]->pages == 1){
    $results = $wpdb->get_results( 'SELECT * FROM '.$wpdb->prefix.'posts WHERE post_status="publish" AND (post_type="page" OR post_type="post") ORDER BY post_title ASC', OBJECT );                          
}

if($option[0]->pages == 1 && $option[0]->posts == 0){
   $results = $wpdb->get_results( 'SELECT * FROM '.$wpdb->prefix.'posts WHERE post_status="publish" AND post_type="page" ORDER BY post_title ASC', OBJECT );
}

if($option[0]->pages == 0 && $option[0]->posts == 1){
   $results = $wpdb->get_results( 'SELECT * FROM '.$wpdb->prefix.'posts WHERE post_status="publish" AND post_type="post" ORDER BY post_title ASC', OBJECT );              
}
```

a bit pseudo code of the code above:

if foo = 1 and bar = 1 -> return foo and bar

if foo = 0 and bar = 1 -> return only bar

if foo = 1 and bar = 0 -> return only foo

if foo = 0 and bar = 0 -> return false

You see:

00

10

01

11

00

If I insert another variable I'll get a lot of more opportunities and that is realy bad. Because I'll get realy big if statements.

Can somebody tells me another opportunitie to achive the same result?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd do it like this:

```
$sql_condition = '( 1=2 '; // one fake-condition, just to make it possible to start with 'OR' later

foreach($option[0] as $key => $value) {  // iterate through all possible conditions
    if($value===1) { // maybe exclude $keys that should not be used here
        $sql_condition.=' OR post_type="'.$key.'"';
    }
}
$sql_condition.=')';

$results = $wpdb->get_results( 'SELECT * FROM '.$wpdb->prefix.'posts WHERE post_status="publish" AND '.$sql_condition.' ORDER BY post_title ASC', OBJECT );
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me.
$sql_condition is empty in my case.

Comment: I had to change something but it work now. Thank you.

Comment: will you tell me what you had to change so that I can include into the answer?

Comment: if($value==1 && $key!='id' && $key!='searchbox') {
            $sql_condition.=' OR post_type="'.$key.'"';   
    }

Answer (score 1):

Please try this code :

```
$sub_query = $operator = '';

if($option[0]->posts == 1)
{
    $sub_query = 'post_type="page"';
    $operator = ' OR';
}
if($option[0]->pages == 1)
{
    $sub_query .= $operator.' post_type="post"';
}

if(empty($sub_query))
{
    return false;
}
else
{
$results = $wpdb->get_results( 'SELECT * FROM '.$wpdb->prefix.'posts WHERE post_status="publish" AND ('.$sub_query.') ORDER BY post_title ASC', OBJECT );   
}
```

Comment: If the type increases then it will need to add more `if` conditions. *If I insert another variable I'll get a lot of more opportunities*

Comment: $option[0]->posts and $option[0]->pages have only two values only 1 or 0.

Comment: Yes. But I need a script which can handle 001, 010, 100... or maybe 0001, 0010, 0100 ....

Answer (score 0):

Create an array($arr) and set the key like "0,0" and value like "$sql";
and your code will be like this:

```
$tempKey = $option[0]->pages . "," . $option[0]->posts;
if(isset($arr[$tempKey]) {
     $results = $wpdb->get_results($arr[$tempKey]); 
}
```

So when you want to add more pages and posts all you will do is to change the arr.

Answer (score 0):

```
$types = [];
if ($option[0]->posts)
    $types[] = '"post"';
if ($option[0]->pages)
    $types[] = '"page"';
if (!$types)
    return null;
$results = $wpdb->get_results( 'SELECT * FROM '.$wpdb->prefix.'posts WHERE post_status="publish" AND (post_type IN ('. implode(',', $types) .')) ORDER BY post_title ASC', OBJECT );
```

Comment: I try it.
But thats my issue:
Unknown column 'post' in 'where clause'

Comment: You need to fix the errors in the query related to `quote`s.